# passing values from one jsf page to another through managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, jsf-2

i need to pass a value(studentId) from a jsf view(list.xhtml) to another jsf page (editor.xhtml) via managed bean (bean.java). I can get the values in  bean page but i could not access those in editor . Can you please tell me what went wrong ?
Hope to hear some suggestions

list.xhtml

```
    <h:dataTable  value="#{student.createList()}" var="student" styleClass="studentTable"
                         columnClasses=",,,fixedWidth" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Student ID</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{student.studentId}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
           <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{student.fname}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Surname</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{student.lname}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
  <h:commandLink  actionListener="#{student.edit()}" value ="Editt">
                             <f:param name="id" value="#{student.studentId}"/>

                         </h:commandLink>
```

editor.xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid border="" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="20" columns="3">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Student Id" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{student.studentId}" readonly="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Id is Required" id="Eid">
                        </h:inputText> <h:message for="Eid"/>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Student Name" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{student.fname}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is Required" id="Ename">

                        </h:inputText> <h:message for="Ename"/>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Student Age" />
                            <h:inputText value="#{student.lname}" required="true" requiredMessage="age is Required" id="Eage">

 <h:commandLink value="Update" action="userRecords" actionListener="#{student.update()}">

                        </h:commandLink>
```

student.java

> ```
> public void edit(){
>      System.out.println("called from edit()"+ this.StudentId);
>
>         List<Student> arrList = createList();
>          FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
> mapParam=fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap();
>
>         String idStudent;
>         HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
>
>
>         for (Student studentManagedBean : arrList) {
>             if (studentManagedBean.getStudentId() == idStudent) {
>                 this.setStudentId(studentManagedBean.getStudentId());//Error
>                 this.setFname(studentManagedBean.getFname());
>                 this.setLname(studentManagedBean.getLname());
>
>             }
> System.out.println(" we have "+ this.getStudentId() + this.getFname() );
>         }
>
>
>  }
> ```

```
 public void update() {
         Connection conn=null;
      try{

           Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/XX","XX","XXX");
      }catch(Exception e){

      }
       String str = "Update student set FNAME=?,LNAME=? where STUDENTID=?";
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
         int  idStudent = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        try {

           PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
            pstmt.setString(1, this.getFname());
            pstmt.setString(2, this.getLname());
            pstmt.setInt(3, idStudent);
//            System.out.println("Id Student Update :" + idStudent);//Error
            int executeUpdate = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if (executeUpdate > 0) {
                System.out.println("Update SuccessFully");

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {

        }
```

Comment: What is the relation of jdbc to this question

Comment: I see you commented "Error" somewhere in the code. Did you mean that the line in question threw an exception? Why don't you share the exception with us? Good exceptions namely represent the whole explanation to the problem! Being unable to interpret them doesn't mean that you should ignore them as if they are irrelevant. Real programmers can explain exceptions in layman's terms for you so that you finally understand them and can see and solve the problem yourselves. Moreover, when you copypaste a good exception and if necessary 1st line of stack into a search engine, you'll get a lot of clues.